# how to transfer a php array to javascript using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

to all I would like to get a php list in order to use it in javascript, I would like this list to be on another page, so I thought about using ajax by browsing on different forums, I found other forums ( on stackoverflow and other) with the same objective as mine except that I tried their solutions but the feedback is a blank page, i think that the problem is that the posts were from 7 years ago, so i thought the way to do it maybe changed, my code is as follows:

test2.php

```php
<?php

 $a = ["string1","string2"];
('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($a);
?>
```

test3.php

```
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


      <script>


      $( document ).ready(function() { 

      $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('test2.php'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
   }
 });


      </script>
```

My objective is to have an alert box that displays the array.

Comment: Does your web alert after submitting?

Comment: Change `alert(data)` to `console.log(data)` and then check the console

Comment: Thanks for your answers, The alert works if i understand your question correctly, and i changed to console.log(data) but nothing happens in the console.

Answer (score 0):

php side

```
$myArray = array("value1", "value2");
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

Client side

```
 <html>

<head>
  <title>example</title>

</head>

<body>
  <p>Test</p>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

  <script>
      $(function() {

        $.ajax({
        url: "./test2.php",
       type: 'POST',
       contentType:'application/json',
       data: {},
       dataType:"json",
       success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
       }
      });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Please check chrome developer tools ( ctrl + shift + i ) console tab

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this code but nothing shows in the console.

Comment: Please try to add `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before echo line in php file, make sure that request submitted to `http://yoursite.com/path/to/test2.php`,  please check dev tools network tab, and please write the request url and response body, i think you have to change `site_url` to be `base_url`

Comment: thanks for your answer, how do i make sure that request submitted to http://yoursite.com/path/to/test2.php ?

Comment: you can check this by open chrome development tools ` ctrl + shift + i ` ,then refresh your page while dev tools is opened, check if `console` tab has error messages or not , then open `network` tab you will find in left side all requests from front side to the server click on your request, check in right side `headers` tab, `request url` and in `response` tab the response from the server, for more info about [chrome dev tools network](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/)

Comment: The console message hasns't got error messages, in the headers tab, i don't see any header to test2.php

Comment: thanks for your response, but what do you mean by that ?

Comment: edit your question and write the full code in booth files `test3.php` and `test2.php`

Comment: Okay now we got it, you have to define `<script> $.ajax ....</script>` after importing jquery packages to be in the bottom of the page, also you have to wrap ajax code in document ready `$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax ...
});` , then open dev tools network tab and refresh the page

Comment: also why you are using many versions from jquery lib, use only one version.

Comment: thanjs a lot, the console stills gives me blank page, I am editind the post to show the new test2.php

Comment: check the updated answer and update test2.php file to be the same and give it a try

Comment: thanks for the updated answer, but the console is still blank.

Comment: Sorry add this to test3.php the front end file, this code works with me, I want to confirm that you are running the php server and opening this files from the server/path/file/test3.php

Comment: What do I have to add to test3.php ?

Comment: please join [this room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198615/discussing-and-issue)

Comment: Hey i joined but I don't have yet the 20 of rep

Comment: Hi i did remove all code inside it and add the html code which i mentioned in the answer but the console is still blank.